# How to get the width of y-axis label in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

How to get the width of left y-axis label? or the space between the start of chart and y-axis

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "width? Is it the value in density-pixels? Or you want to get number 40 or more?

Comment: Can you specify what version of MPAndroidChart you are using please?

Comment: @MichałDobiDobrzański , yes the width pixel of the longest label

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would like the get the longest label width then you can do:

```
chart.getRendererLeftYAxis()
     .getPaintAxisLabels()
     .measureText(chart.getAxisLeft().getLongestLabel())
```

Or you can get the margins on either side of the labels:

```
chart.getAxisLeft().getXOffset()
```

Or you can get the axis width (which are the last two values combined):

```
chart.getAxisLeft().getRequiredWidthSpace(
    chart.getRendererLeftYAxis().getPaintAxisLabels())
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate any side gaps, you can also use `chart.viewPortHandler`

```
chart.viewPortHandler.offsetLeft()
chart.viewPortHandler.offsetRight()
chart.viewPortHandler.offsetTop()
chart.viewPortHandler.offsetBottom()
```

This offset includes labels width and axis offset.