# danielgindi/Charts: get left yAxis width

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to get the left yAxis width? I'm drawing custom markers and would like to avoid to draw over the left yAxis.

There is a solution for the android version of this library but it doesn't work in iOS because of different render methods: [How to get the width of y-axis label in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875227/how-to-get-the-width-of-y-axis-label-in-mpandroidchart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the axis width by the `requiredSize()` method.

> chartView.leftAxis.requiredSize()

This is what `requiredSize()` method actually does:

```
@objc open func requiredSize() -> CGSize
{
    let label = getLongestLabel() as NSString
    var size = label.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: labelFont])
    size.width += xOffset * 2.0
    size.height += yOffset * 2.0
    size.width = max(minWidth, min(size.width, maxWidth > 0.0 ? maxWidth : size.width))
    return size
}
```

Use this only after you set the chart data, cause the chart will automatically calculate the width with the longest label in your axis.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
let yourBarChartView = BarChartView()
let leftAxis = yourBarChartView.leftAxis
let width = leftAxis.axisLineWidth
```

Hope this helps!